# Series Problem in CIPS Panel cointegration test

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I am in difficulty estimating the CIPS panel cointergration test in R. I load the plm package and make the panel data a pdata frame

```
bcc_panel3 <- pdata.frame(bcc_panel3,index = c("date","country"))
```

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cXBZ.png)

The dataset containes 3 variables.
The R command I used:

```
cipstest(bcc_panel3$BCC_con, lags = 4, type = c("trend"), model=c("cmg"))
```

and I tried variations of it, but always the same message comes up.

```
*Error in difft.pseries(x = x, lag = lag, ...) :  diff is only relevant for numeric or logical series*
```

What is the issue?

Comment: What is the class of the variable? You can check via, e.g., `lapply(bcc_panel3, class)`.

Comment: $date
[1] "character"

$BCC_con
[1] "character"

$country
[1] "factor"

$time
[1] "factor"

Comment: I used 'is.numeric' and 'is.double' to coerce BCC_con to a numeric  value but it failed

Comment: Obviously, numerical computations on characters won't work. Maybe change your data import procedure such that it does not produce character for this variable but a numeric directly.

Comment: It is numeric iniatially but the p.data.frame command creates the character values.

Comment: Can you show that in a reproducible example? Any non-standard packages you use to import the data?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_tRetCRUuFr1Z18xz662YLyN6R1ix7oW/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tK0fKkxY4lXymZTT0QWXst5Dg2cbEMxc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The above links are for the code and data of reproducive example

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in a comment, `plm::pdata.frame` turns your numerical into a non-numerical. In the way you use `pdata.frame` is does so and turns your numerical into a factor. Please read the documentation of `pdata.frame`. Your variable of interest is in the 2nd column of your data frame. If you do not specify the `index` argument to `pdata.frame` it assumes the first two columns to be the indexes and does what it is supposed to do: turn the first two columns into factors. Given that you do not want this variable to be the index, use `pdata.frame` like this:

```
pdata.frame(xy_combine, index = c("country", "date"))
```

(Based on your data and your script provided in the comments of the question.)

Given you data, `cipstest` will, however fail, as you have too few observational units in your (test) data (the error message is not really informative about this). The paper describing the test (Pesaran (2007)) gives tabulated p-values from 10 individuals (observational units) on. You have 2 individuals in your data set.

I give the full script I used below (I stripped down your script to the relevant parts):

```
library(readxl) #library for reading excel files
library("plm")
#import data
test <- read_excel("C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/test.xlsx") # adjust to your path

#create country column with 60 obs each Austria and Belgium
country <- rep(c("Austria","Belgium"), each=60)

#stack xy columns into a single column
attach(test)
df1 <- data.frame(a=x, b=y)
xy <- data.frame(c(df1[,"a"],df1[,"b"]))

#create panel data
date <-test$date
xy_combine <- cbind(date, xy, country)
xy_panel <- pdata.frame(xy_combine, index = c("country", "date")) # specify index

lapply(xy_panel, class) # factor, numeric, factor

#rename column 2 in xy_panel1
colnames(xy_panel)[2] <- "xy_con"

#order data by country
country_order <- order(xy_panel$country)
xy_panel1<- xy_panel[country_order,]

lapply(xy_panel1, class) # factor, numeric, factor


cipstest(xy_panel1$xy_con,lag=2, type=c("none")) # errors. Likely to few individuals in data set.
```

Comment: The index in pdata.frame command wil not resolve the issue the following error message appears:                                                                            
  **Error in difft.pseries(x = x, lag = lag, ...) :  diff is only relevant for numeric or logical series**

Comment: The series under examination remains _character_

Comment: Please see my edit with the full script, I used plm version 2.2-5 (as currently on CRAN).

Comment: I am using the 2.2-5 version of plm, too. The error message now is different _Error in approx(nintv, cvals[nintl:ninth, tintl, i], n = max(nintv) -  : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate_ What could be the cause of it?

Comment: See my answer... I put a note there

Comment: I expended the **"width"** of the data. the _xy_con_ variable has the dimesion 240x1, now. The same error message comes up. Is the problem the **"length"** of the series under examination ?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean with width and length. If you do not bring the number of entities in the individual dimension (countries in your case) to at least 10, you will see the same error. This is rather a statistical issue. The programming question has been answered.

Comment: By "width" I mean the cross sectional units and by "length" the number of time periods.

Comment: So "width" in your words. Btw: The time dimension per cross sectional unit has a minimum as well.

Comment: Which is the limit of time dimension for R ?

Comment: Please do have a look at the paper for the test cited in my answer.